# Referencing a NuGet Package's Tools From Another Package

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I have a NuGet package (MyPkg) that contains a build target which is dependent on build tasks in another package (AnotherPkg). AnotherPkg has a tools directory with that build task DLL. Following NuGet behavior, the DLL is installed to \packages\AnotherPkg.0.1.1\tools

I am wondering if there is a proper way to reference AnotherPkg's tools path and make it version agnostic. For example, I'd like the package user to be able to upgrade AnotherPkg to 0.1.2, and not have to change anything in my package.

I have some code that kind of works to try and find AnotherPkg's directory... but it seems a little flaky and the project might not load if AnotherPkg has not yet been installed.

```
<ItemGroup>  
    <AnotherPkgDll Include="$(SolutionDir)\packages\AnotherPkg.*\tools\AnotherPkg.Tasks.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="@(AnotherPkgDll)" TaskName="Whatever" />
```

Any other tips? I'm hoping I'm missing some sort of NuGet function to get this info.

Comment: Don't rely on $(SolutionDir), you won't be able to build on the command line without a solution file.  Instead use $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\AnotherPkg.*, and consider using a user customizable property to fix the version number of AnotherPkg, as AnotherPkg.$(AnotherPkgVersion)\tools\AnotherPkg.tasks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The package I'm trying to use in my package is on Github. So I modified it and submitted a pull request. :)